# What properties of MOND differ from Newtonian gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, definition, modified-gravity

I know of the following properties that set [modified Newtonian dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics) (MOND) apart from Newtonian gravity:

- There is a $1/r$ dependence instead of a $1/r^2$ dependence, at large distances/low accelerations.
- Higher gravitational attraction, at large distances, compared to Newtonian gravitation.
- The strong equivalence principle does not hold.
- The external field effect is expected: internal dynamics depends on the external gravitational field, for small internal accelerations.

Are there more such qualitative differences between MOND (even if they apply only to one of its specific forms) and Newtonian gravity?

Comment: Are you talking about conventional MOND, or one of the relativistic generalizations of it like TeVeS gravity?

Comment: Any type of MOND is interesting.

Comment: MOND is a theory with no physical motivation; It exists only to fit one item of experimental data.  It supporters "do not like" dark matter, so rather than allowing just a _single_ parameter in GR to change, they want to throw out the whole theory and replace it with something more convenient.  It will be interesting to see how long it persists.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing dark energy (a single parameter in GR) and dark matter. Dark matter is not a single parameter, but many, and has no experimental evidence.

Comment: @m4r35n357, Dark matter is a theory with no physical motivation; It exists only to fit one item of experimental data. It supporters "do not like" MOND, so rather than allowing just a *single* parameter in GR to change, they want to vandalize the whole standard model theory and throw in something more convenient. It will be interesting to see how long it persists.

Comment: @MadMax Your comment should be about _General Relativity_, not "Dark Matter" to be logically inconsistent with mine.

Comment: @Gerd-Jan I think the matter density of the universe is a _single parameter_ in basic GR cosmology.  Please correct me if that is wrong.

Comment: "Dark matter" is not a single parameter in Galaxies.